# Javascript - Remove certain character in an element

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a input box with value 'jklmnop', how would I go about removing 'k' using javascript?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
<input type='text' id='letters' value='jklmnop'/>
<button onclick='removeK()'>Remove</button
```

Using this javascript:

```
function removeK() {
    document.getElementById('letters').value.replace('k','');
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work? And if so, what would I need to  do to make it work?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting the value.

```
var l = document.getElementById('letters');
l.value = l.value.replace('k','');
```